# SwiftUI preview works fine, but Running it does not

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom toggle button that runs fine in preview, but shows just white when i run it in simulator... any idea?

[image]

in the simulator it shows

[image]

Here is what im running

The custom toggle button is

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    var label1: String
    var label2: String
    
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ToggleItem(isOn: configuration.isOn, label1: label1, label2: label2)
                 .onTapGesture {
                    configuration.isOn.toggle()
                 }
    }
    

    struct ToggleItem: View {
        var isOn: Bool
        var label1: String
        var label2: String
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .fill(Color.toggleBG)
                    .frame(width: 340, height: 60)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(.white)
                            .frame(width: 149, height: 50)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8),
                        
                        alignment: isOn ? .trailing : .leading
                    )
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2))
                    .overlay(
                        Text(label1)
                            .font(.custom(isOn ? "regular" : "heavy", size: 18)).foregroundColor(isOn ? .white : Color.toggleBG)
                                .padding(.trailing, 178),
                             alignment: .center)
                    .overlay(
                        Text(label2)
                            .font(.custom(isOn ? "heavy" : "regular", size: 18)).foregroundColor(isOn ? Color.toggleBG : .white)
                                .padding(.leading, 178),
                             alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```

This is the view

```
@State private var test: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.BGColor
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){

                    Toggle(isOn: $test){
                        Text("toggle")
                    }.toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle(label1: "Test1", label2: "Test2"))
                        .padding(.bottom, 25)
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
```

Comment: They both work here. Xcode 13.2.1, iOS 15.2

Comment: You'd have to include your `Color` customizations for this to be runnable. My suspicion is that you have an issue with light mode/dark mode on your device changing the way the colors appear.

Comment: Good point. I substituted in .gray for the custom color.